# Sum of Text Boxes in Single Row of Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sum up all the textboxes of a single row in a dynamic table.  As I am not fluent in JavaScript, I would appreciate all the help I can get.

For the following function, the original .each() implementation is still valid, but I want to have it so that it only totals the text boxes in `roway`.

```
    function calcf(){
var tableb = document.getElementById('dataTable');
var sdf = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i<1; i++) {
var roway=tableb.rows[i];
var huehue = roway.cells[0].childNodes[0];
var currentt=0;
$(".txt").each(function() {
  currentt+=parseFloat(this.value);
});
sdf.push(currentt);
}
$("#asdf").html(sdf[0]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(roway).find(".txt").each(function() {
  currentt+=parseFloat(this.value);
});
```